# Pass name index of model, into a field of another model - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def create_print(self):
    rec_production_order = self.env['bsi.production.order'].browse(1)
    self.env['bsi.print.order'].create({
        'origin': rec_production_order.id,
        'state': 'draft',
    })
```

Which should create another model, from `bsi.production.order`, these are the two complete models:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'
    _inherit = ['product.product']

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            if vals.get('production_type') == 'budgeted':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'nonbudgeted':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.non_budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'direct':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.direct') or '/'
        return super(bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
    print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")

class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread','mrp.worksheet.contract'] 

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Print Date")
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    origin = fields.Char(string="Origin")
    due_date = fields.Date(string="Due Date")
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
        ('wip','Work in Progress'),
        ('delivered','Delivered'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string="State")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
```

The method works, but on `origin` field from `bsi.print.order` it just creates a 1, it is supposed to be the `name` from `bsi.production.order`, not a number, also, what is weird about this, is the fact that, no matter how many print orders I create, it always puts a number 1 in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you're assigning Char field `origin` with the id of the first record of `bsi.production.order` (which is `1`, you're explisitly browsing it).
If you want to put there a `name` of the `bsi.production.order`, then try this:

```
@api.multi
def create_print(self):
    rec_production_order = self.env['bsi.production.order'].browse(1)
    self.env['bsi.print.order'].create({
        'origin': rec_production_order.name,
        'state': 'draft',
    })
```

There's another possible mistake in your code. If you'll use the code from above, you'll quickly find out, that each time you're creating a new `bsi.print.order` record, you'll assign it's name with the first record of the `bsi.production.order`. Probably, it's not what you wanted. Try to replace

```
rec_production_order = self.env['bsi.production.order'].browse(1)
```

with `search()`, or something else.

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, yes, indfeed, do You have a clue of which method or domain should I use for ´self.env´?

Comment: I don't know the business logic of your code, but I'm guessing, you need to somehow select a record from your `bsi.poduction.order`. Use `self.env['bsi.production.order'].search([], order='id desc', limit=1)`. This will retrieve the last created record from the model. Keep in mind, if the model is empty, you'll catch "Expected singleton record" exception.